# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Responsive Resizing issue

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

At https://filathlos.imagewize.com/ I have a WordPress website with a Bootstrap 4 carousel in progress. I am struggling to get the images for all slides to resize properly, to make the carousel responsive.

Right now the first two slides are resizing as they should. The final slide is bigger on resize (when I make the browser smaller). Besides the carousel.scss I have the following now:

```
/* -------------------------------------------------
*
* Slider
*
* ------------------------------------------------*/
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 678px) {
.carousel {
    max-height: 500px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
   .carousel {
    max-height: 700px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*max-width: 1120px;*/
}

.ct-div-block {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 25px 25px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

And this is the html output

```
<div class="container-fluid b4-slider">
    <!-- Carousel -->
      <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                              <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
                              <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                          </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img width="2000" height="1500" src="https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/curtis-mac-newton-running.jpg" class="img-responsive responsive--full wp-post-image" alt="" title="Feature image" srcset="https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/curtis-mac-newton-running.jpg 2000w, https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/curtis-mac-newton-running-300x225.jpg 300w, https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/curtis-mac-newton-running-768x576.jpg 768w, https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/curtis-mac-newton-running-1024x768.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 2000px) 100vw, 2000px">                                  <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text carousel-caption hidden-xs">
                      <div class="ct-div-block">
                            <h2>
                                                                <span>Running is freedom</span>
                                                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                                                            <span><p><em>“Praesent At Dignissim Ex, A Ultricies Felis. Donec Sagittis Justo Imperdiet, Gravida Odio Id, Porttitor Urna. In Et Purus Nibh. Nunc Tempor Augue Eleifend Velit Eleifend Ornare.”</em><br>
– Brenda Schultz, Multicerv</p>
</span>
                                                          </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
          </div><!-- end item -->
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img width="2426" height="1728" src="https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/25.5-of-the-web.jpeg" class="img-responsive responsive--full wp-post-image" alt="" title="Feature image" srcset="https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/25.5-of-the-web.jpeg 2426w, https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/25.5-of-the-web-300x214.jpeg 300w, https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/25.5-of-the-web-768x547.jpeg 768w, https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/25.5-of-the-web-1024x729.jpeg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 2426px) 100vw, 2426px">                                  <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text carousel-caption hidden-xs">
                      <div class="ct-div-block">
                            <h2>
                                                                <span>Laptop</span>
                                                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                                                            <span><p>Slide number two</p>
</span>
                                                          </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
          </div><!-- end item -->
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img width="3001" height="1998" src="https://filathlos.imagewize.com/app/uploads/2017/03/adjust-on-the-fly-e1489331922966.jpeg" class="img-responsive responsive--full wp-post-image" alt="" title="Feature image">                                  <!-- Static Header -->
                    <div class="header-text carousel-caption hidden-xs">
                      <div class="ct-div-block">
                            <h2>
                                                                <span>On the Fly</span>
                                                            </h2>
                            <br>
                            <h3>
                                                            <span><p>Slide number one.</p>
</span>
                                                          </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /header-text -->
          </div><!-- end item -->
                            </div> <!-- end carousel inner -->
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /carousel -->
  </div>
```

I prefer the slider to deal with images of different sizes so that is why I am working with a max-height and fluid width.

Any ideas how I can improve upon this and make all slides keep the same height and width as the slideshow is resized?

**P.S.** Wanted to include standard queries using @ and import the Bootstrap named ones, but somehow had errors.

Comment: When I made the third slide image 2000px by 1500px the resizing started to work OK. Is it perhaps an image ratio issue?

Comment: if it is a image ratio issue, when i build websites with backend ruby on rails i use imagemagick gem for fixing the image ratio issue. still very hard to help you because it is difficult without seeing the actual website

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Did adjust the url and you can check the site now. Working on a possible WordPress way to store all uploaded images a certain size so they resize properly . But I wonder here whether the CSS is all good here.

Comment: I checked mobile responsibe at 360px and also above. the three images looks fine. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: It is fine now that I made the images of ratio 0.75. But I wanted to be able to upload an image in any size and get it to resize responsively regardless of its dimensions.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. 
This is my search, you need to use jquery to fix this and search for some sort of plugin like the rails gem imagemagick. Maybe something even for wordpress. Otherwise cropping it with css may not work well
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jquery+imagemagick&t=lm&ia=web